# Schedule meeting

Tags: scheduling, doodle.com

I know about [Doodle](https://www.doodle.com) and I've used it for a while to schedule meetings but it has one big drawback: If I'm available between 10-13 for a meeting that should take one hour, then I might schedule it like this:

- 10-11
- 11-12
- 12-13

But I'm also available for 11:30-12:30. That, however, doesn't show up. And If someone can’t do 10-11 or 11-12 but is free for only 11:30-12:30 then the person can't say that.

Thus, I want to draw to say “I'm available between 10 and 13 for a 1 hour meeting.”

How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK Google Calendar has the same shortcoming regarding appointment slots. (demo http://www.googlegooru.com/how-to-create-and-reserve-appointment-slots/)

Comment: This is now out of date. Doodle supports overlapping meetings.